# Error: The method `CircularNotchedRectangle` is not defined

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to create a widget using the BottomAppBar. It is using `CircularNotchedRectangle` but it gives me this error:

> The method `CircularNotchedRectangle`  is not defined

Does anyone know what is the reason?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:roomie/screens/widgets/common_drawer.dart';

class CommonScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle;
  final Widget bodyData;
  final showFAB;
  final showDrawer;
  final backGroundColor;
  final actionFirstIcon;
  final scaffoldKey;
  final showBottomNav;
  final floatingIcon;
  final centerDocked;
  final elevation;

  CommonScaffold(
      {this.appTitle,
      this.bodyData,
      this.showFAB = false,
      this.showDrawer = false,
      this.backGroundColor,
      this.actionFirstIcon = Icons.search,
      this.scaffoldKey,
      this.showBottomNav = false,
      this.centerDocked = false,
      this.floatingIcon,
      this.elevation = 4.0});

  Widget myBottomBar() => new BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Ink(
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: UIData.kitGradients)),
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: new InkWell(
                  radius: 10.0,
                  splashColor: Colors.yellow,
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Center(
                    child: new Text(
                      "ADD TO WISHLIST",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new SizedBox(
                width: 20.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: new InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  radius: 10.0,
                  splashColor: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Center(
                    child: new Text(
                      "ORDER PAGE",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey != null ? scaffoldKey : null,
      backgroundColor: backGroundColor != null ? backGroundColor : null,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: elevation,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(appTitle),
        actions: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 5.0,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(actionFirstIcon),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: showDrawer ? CommonDrawer() : null,
      body: bodyData,
      floatingActionButton: showFAB
          ? CustomFloat(
              builder: centerDocked
                  ? Text(
                      "5",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0),
                    )
                  : null,
              icon: floatingIcon,
              qrCallback: () {},
            )
          : null,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: centerDocked
          ? FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked
          : FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      bottomNavigationBar: showBottomNav ? myBottomBar() : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered heres what I think might be the cause. There have been some [breaking changes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18372) to the API recently, so if your version is not up to date you will need to use the previous `BottomAppBar` API:

`BottomAppBar(shape: CircularNotchedRectangle())` was previously `BottomAppBar(hasNotch: true)`

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flutter-dev/4So9TmC-PG8/neZ7Uo-4BgAJ)